# Deleting and adding items in a table Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, listobject

I've got a problem with filling a table.

The table will be filled with data after a combobox is changed. First off I want to delete the data that's in the table and after that add the data I want.

What I have got is this (This is just a part of the code, the collection is already filled with data)

```
Dim TableListObject As ListObject
Dim TableObjectRow As ListRow
Dim i As Integer
Dim CollWerknemer as Collection

Set TableListObject = TheSheet.ListObjects(1)
Set TableObjectRow = TableListObject.ListRows.Add

TableListObject.DataBodyRange.Delete 

i = 1
For Each vNum In CollWerknemer
    TableObjectRow.Range(i, 1) = vNum
    i = i + 1
Next vNum
```

The problem is that it does delete the table but doesn't add anything.

If I exclude the `TableListObject.DataBodyRange.Delete` from the code it does fill the table with the data that I want, but if I change my combobox the new data will be added at the bottom instead of clearing the table first.

Answer (score 0):

First you could iterate each row in the current table, and remove its content, then use the ListRows.Add

```
With outTBL
    If .ListRows.Count >= 1 Then
        .DataBodyRange.Delete
    End If
End With

Dim row as ListRow
Set row = outTBL.ListRows.Add

row.Range(x, x) = vNum
```

Comment: I changed outTBL to TableListObject, because I think thats what you want to count, then it says that the argument is not optional.

Comment: What I ment is that the exact same thing works fine for me, but I initiate my ListRow after deleting the DataBodyRange. Maybe that it is the case?